# make a unique, random number to use as an order ID

Tags: php

I'm working right now to get a unique order number for the item being purchased.

The problem is such that I have payment gateway at quickpay and it comes up and says this: "**Error in field: ordernumber**"

I have tried to make it like this:

```
$idag = date("dmY");
    $a = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@!*_-?>/+,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 4);
    $total = $idag . $a;


    $sql = "SELECT pakker.pris FROM pakker WHERE pakker.id = 3";
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($pris);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $protocol = '7';
            $msgtype = 'authorize';
            $merchant = '89898978';
            $language = 'da';
            $ordernumber = $total;// here must order number came up.
```

I have also tried to do it like this.

```
$idag = date("dmY");
        $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())), 0,8));
        $a = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@!*_-?>/+,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 4);
        $total = $idag . $a . $rand;
```

Comment: Do you know why quickpay is saying that there is an error? Is there a set format for order numbers?

Comment: @ialarmedalien No, I do not know but I tried just before a time and it works just fine with no problems but now I have problems.

Comment: where have you defined $mysqli ?

Comment: @ialarmedalien There is no difference, I did not add anything or remove anything at all on the page.

Comment: @AvinashBabu Want to see the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API documentation for Quickpay]:

> **ordernumber**
>
> `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}$/`
>
> A value by merchant's own choice. Must be unique for each transaction. Usually an incrementing sequence. The value may be reflected in the your bank account list.

You need to alter your random order ID generator to exclude any non-alphanumeric characters.

i.e.

```
$idag = date("dmY");
$a = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 4);
$total = $idag . $a;
```

if I were you, I'd use the unix timestamp and then add a few extra characters to the end.